# How to run a local branch on the server

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up git on aws recently and it's been working great. I have been able to push my changes to aws and ran it there to make sure everything works correctly on the server.
However, when I made a local branch to add a feature and pushed that local branch to aws, the files didn't update like they do when I "git push aws master". I checked "git remote show aws" and I do see that my local branch is on aws.

How do I get aws to run the local branch instead of the master? I want to make sure the feature is completely done before committing it back to the master branch.
Also, what's generally the recommended workflow? (For example, to setup a local testing server?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment so I'd like to ask if you have pushed the branch to the git repository in aws?

basically, whenever I create a branch from master:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

I make sure to push it to the git server first by:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>
```

then I add the files I need, or if it would be just like the copy of the master, I just add, commit and push the master branch's files that were left after switching from the master branch to the new branch.

Then if you would switch to the branch in the server, use

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

so it will be on the branch

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

`git push -u origin --all`

Explanation: [http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+push+-u+origin+--all](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git%20push%20-u%20origin%20--all)

It will push all the branches to origin! (replace `origin` with `aws` in your case)